# Problems rooting a Pandigital Planet 7 tablet

Tags: rooting

I have problems rooting a PanDigital Planet 7 tablet.
I've already tried some instructions (including this one: http://www.the-ebook-reader.com/pandigital-planet-root.html), but there is an error:

mount/media succeed!

--Install /sdcard...
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installing update...
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device")=="pandigitalplnt1" || getprop
("ro.build.product")=="pandigitalplnt1"
E: Error in /tnp/sideload/package.zip
(Status 7)
Instalation aborted.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the update is for a device with the codename `pandigitalplnt1`, not the Planet 7. You need to find one for your *exact* device model.